# upload images to active storage with description text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-7

I am building an inspection app. in my inspection model there are a lot of images and each image has comments and location addresses. as I am new to rails & don't know much how to implement this. sample required output is [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgExm.png)
Is there anything else you need to know or see from me?

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate model `DefectPhoto` like this

```
class DefectPhoto < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image
end
```

And add to `defect_photos` columns `address` and `comments` in migration like this

```
create_table :defect_photos do |t|
  t.string :address
  t.string :comments

  t.timestamps
end
```

And if need make associations with other models